# Network 180x slower than Windows or VPN solution

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, realtek, aws

I am having extremely low speed for AWS downloads on Ubuntu and I started to investigate. Here is what I found:

| OS | Configuration | S3 AWS eu-west-1 | Oookla Speedtest Download |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ubuntu 20.10 | Kernel 5.8.0-50 driver | **0.121 MB/s** | **175 Mbit/s** |
| Ubuntu 20.10 | Realtek driver (r8168-dkms) | **0.107 MB/s** | 120 Mbit/s |
| Ubuntu 20.10 | ExpressVPN Singapore (UDP) | 13 MB/s | 217 Mbit/s |
| Ubuntu 20.10 | ExpressVPN Singapore (Lightway UDP) | **15 MB/s** | 732 Mbit/s |
| Ubuntu 20.10 | AirVPN Singapore (Eddie with OpenVPN) | 0.150 MB/s | 217 Mbit/s |
| Ubuntu 21.04 | Kernel 5.11.0-16 driver, Live CD | 0.165 MB/s | 157 Mbit/s |
| Windows 10 | Realtek Driver from Windows Update | **22.0 MB/s** | 947 Mbit/s |
| Windows 10 | ExpressVPN Singapore (UDP) | *14 MB/s* | 287 Mbit/s |
| Windows 10 | ExpressVPN Singapore (Lightway UDP) | 16 MB/s | 759 Mbit/s |
| Windows 10 | AirVPN Singapore (Eddie Wintune) | *14 MB/s* | 556 Mbit/s |

As you can see I get really bad performance on my Ubuntu: 121 KB/s instead of 22 MB/s on Windows 10. That is **180 times slower**! I even installed the Realtek kernel driver, with no difference. It made it even slightly worse. I have this problem with other services as well, like github clones.

Interestingly I get very good performance with ExpressVPN, in both their UDP and lightway implementation. With AirVPN that uses OpenVPN although the performance is again very bad.

On Windows 10 I get good performance throughout.

I also tried a newer kernel 5.11 with the Ubuntu 21.04 live CD. Still the problem is the same.

**Any ideas what I can do to get good performance without any VPN solution?**

Here is my system:

```
System: Lenovo Legion 5 15ACH6H
Ubuntu: 20.10 64 bit
Kernel: 5.8.0-50-generic

# sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: **************
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-50-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:92 ioport:1000(size=256) memory:d1804000-d1804fff memory:d1800000-d1803fff


# ifconfig
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether *************  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3052960  bytes 3564513260 (3.5 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1275673  bytes 967469746 (967.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 1 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 61  base 0x1000
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the way you've designed your chart, but the identical scenarios seem to be performing at roughly the same speed.  Upload/Download speed is determined by dozens of factors, including the upload speed of the *server*.  You can really only compare the two operating systems' performance when all other factors are identical. Downloading the same file from two different sources can't be used for meaningful comparison.  There's also factors you can't control like temporary congestion or traffic being routed differently from one test to another.

Comment: I am downloading the same AWS file. And it happens deterministically. Switching VPN off, downloading with 100 kb/s. Switching on, downloading with 10+MB/s. Switching off again 100 kb/s. So I don't think it is an external issue. I tried many many times and it is consistently slow over days and weeks now without a VPN. And consistently fast with a VPN.

Comment: Your traffic is routed completely differently when using a VPN.  You can't blame any OS when you are manipulating other variables.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. And on Windows I get 10+ MB/s always without a VPN. On Linux, same machine, it is always around 100 kb/s. Even when rebooting very quickly and downloading the same file.

Comment: It must be a driver issue. I just attached an external USB ethernet interface and get 10+ MB on Linux without a VPN.

Comment: Any idea where I should report such an issue?